# What is the JavaScript Engine used in Opera Next (Or 12+)

Tags: opera, javascript-engine

Is it WebKit? Presto? Is V8 engine dedicated to Chrome alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebKit and Presto are not Javascript engines, but rendering engines. Opera previously used a Javascript engine called "Carakan", but have since started transitioning from Presto and Carakan to Blink and V8.

Comment: oh..yeah. So we can say that Webkit and V8 are the current rendering engines in opera12/Opera next?

Comment: Yes, all versions after 12.15 use the Blink engine in combination with V8.

Comment: okay..thanks! Any links which can provide me the exact info on it?

Comment: Wikipedia seems to be your best stop. Such as: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Opera_web_browser#Version_15

Comment: Note Opera 14 for Android is WebKit (it's based on a pre-fork version of the Chromium Content API).

Comment: Is this is why Opera's dev tool look almost identical to Chrome's? Due to V8?

Answer (score 1):

As per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_(layout_engine)#cite_note-3):

> It remained in use until Opera 12.15, when the browser's developer Opera Software ASA began phasing Presto out of its products in favor of the WebKit layout engine and V8 JavaScript engine combined with a modified Chromium browser.

For more , you can go through [Web specifications support in Opera Presto 2.12](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.12/).